# MongoDB custom wrapper code check: Am I writing ok code?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I'm wondering if the code I have written here is sane and follows the rule of non-blocking, I come from a Java background so I'm new to non-blocking event loop of Node.js.

retard.js:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var retard = {};

retard.getDb = function (url) { // url example 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject'
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

            // custom functions
            db.getCollection = function (mCollection) {
                var obj = {};

                var collection = db.collection(mCollection);
                // access to the native drivers
                obj.native = collection;

                obj.findOne = function (query) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        collection.findOne(query, function (err, result) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            resolve(result);
                        });
                    });
                };

                return obj;
            };
            resolve(db);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = retard;
```

This would then be used as following:

```
var co = require('co');
var config = require('./config');
var retard = require('./lib/retard');

co(function* () {
    var db =
        yield retard.getDb(config.mongodb.url);
    var countries = db.getCollection('countries');

    // first query
    var doc =
        yield countries.findOne({
            country: 'scotland'
        });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));

    // second query
    countries.native.findOne({
        country: 'scotland'
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });

});
```

I get the results I was expecting from the database so it works. I'm just curious as to is this ok *JavaScripting*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there! Something to keep in mind is that that mongodb driver methods already return a Promise if no callback is passed ([findone](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOne)).
Rather than wrapping the methods with a new Promise, you can just return the method itself (a Promise) as follows:

```
    return collection.findOne(query)
```

as opposed to:

```
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    collection.findOne(query, function (err, result) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        resolve(result);
                    });
                });
```

Same applies to MongoClient.connect();

Comment: Ahh you are indeed correct, nice. So I wrote this all in the name of learning! Brilliant so I don't need to give a $h!t about wrapping in Promises, nice, less work for me :) (If it didn't return a Promise though, was the JavaScript correct?)

Comment: Yeah, although I would 'reject(err)' rather than throw it to end up with a full promise that succeeds or fails.